# Excel merge columns

Tags: excel, merge, excel-2003

Hi all I want to merge to columns in excel 2003.

For example:

```
Col1    Col2
------------
1       5
3       4
4       6
7       6
```

The merged column should look like this:

```
Col3
----
1
3
4
4
5
6
6
7
```

Thanks!!

Comment: Using what language? With VBA?

Comment: If it is posible without any code (using excel tools or functions) better. If it is not posible that way then yes, VBA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming, that your **Col1**, **Col2** and **Col3** are Columns **A**, **B** and **C**, you can use makro:

```
Range("A1:" & Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Address).Select
Selection.Copy

Range("C1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

Range("B1:" & Range("B65536").End(xlUp).Address).Offset(1, 0).Select
Selection.Copy

Range("C65536").End(xlUp).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

Source: [link](http://www.excelforum.com/excel-general/567563-combining-data-from-two-columns.html)

Comment: I've got 500 rows in each column and the merged columns turns out with 999 :S

Comment: Did `.Offset(1, 0)` fix your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Although you could easily use Excel's built-in functions to copy and paste the values from each column into the third column, you don't state if it's a requirement that the results in Col3 need to be sorted, or whether duplicate values should be removed or not. If so, you might have to write a user-defined function (equivalent to an Excel macro) in Excel VBA to do this.

Your solution might look like this (pseudo-code):

- Iterate through all rows in Col1 and store values in an array
- Iterate through all rows in Col2 and store values in a second array
- Create a new array and combine the values from the other two arrays
- Output the values from the combined array into Col3

Your function/macro will probably need to accept three input parameters which would be the ranges of the two source columns and the output column.